# Induced emf inducing emf in the same body

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction

A time varying magnetic field will produce an induced emf in a closed loop.
This induced emf will in turn produce an electric current which itself will produce a magnetic field.
My questions are:

1. What are the prerequisites for this to happen?
2. For how long will it continue?
3. What will be the energy losses associated with it?

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what the full set of Maxwell's equations is needed for: to explain the propagation of electromagnetic waves.